# How to approximately match bowtie graphs using igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to learn how `match_vertices` works in `igraph` so that I can use it to join node and attribute information from graphs generated by a few different black box computer programs. I tried looking at the single provided example, but it was too complicated for me to understand. So, I tried to throw together an even simpler toy example which I am trying to understand.

```r
library(igraph)
bow = make_graph(~ A - B - C - A - D - E - A)
tie = make_graph(~ a - e - d - a - c - b - a)
isomorphic(bow, tie)
```

It looks to me like the code should be:

```r
A = get.adjacency(bow)
B = get.adjacency(tie)
P0 = diag(nrow(A))
corr = match_vertices(A, B, 
                      start = P0,
                      m = 0,
                      iteration = 30)
corr$P
```

The permutation matrix didn't seem to change. The resulting permutation matrix is the same as the
starting permutation matrix. Why is that?

I defined a random permutation matrix and repeated the exercise to
see if that was always the case. It was!

```r
random_permutation = function(n, ...) {
  P = diag(n)
  i = sample(1:n, ...)
  P[i,,drop=FALSE]
}
```

Can anyone recommend some simple toy examples of using `match_vertices` that
demonstrate its main features?

1. show how to approximately match two graphs
2. show how to approximately match two graphs when some vertices are known
3. show how to approximately match two graphs when they have different
   numbers of vertices

Also, are there any ways of matching graphs if even if the seeds aren't known
a priori, the nodes have maximally consistent attributes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819381/how-to-measure-approximate-match-between-the-numpy-data-and-a-pattern-model-func